# Maven3 unable to get latest artifact SNAPSHOT version from remote repo

Tags: java, maven, artifactory

I've been facing this error fro quite a while now.
Without being able to trace it back in time precisely, I feel it dates back from the switch to maven3.

Here's what happens:

- I deploy artifact-SNAPSHOT from a server to an Artifactory instance
- I force snapshot update on my local project that depends on artifact-SNAPSHOT

it doesn't work, I may get compilation error that shows the artifact-SNAPSHOT isn't the lastest one.

I have to either delete the local repo version of artifact-SNAPSHOT or get the lastest source and do a local 'mvn install' of artifact-SNAPSHOT.

Anyone facing the problem?
Is it a known bug?
If not, what could I check to understand exactly what happens?

cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug. [Here is a link](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-4142).

If you have worked on module-A (1.2.3-SNAPSHOT) for a while and you've run:

```
mvn clean install
```

This causes your local repository's metadata to 'lock' the artifact, meaning that it won't get updated anymore, as it thinks you're still working on it. So, if, let's say, in a couple of days you start working on module-B which depends on module-A:1.2.3-SNAPSHOT and there is a newer version installed in the remote repository, ***that version*** will completely be ignored. Thus, you'll have to remove the local directory that contains this dependency first and then do:

```
mvn clean install
```

all over again. Passing the `-U` doesn't help at all (which would actually be the natural thing to do).

Comment: The bug seem to concern only dependencies using classifier.
It feels odd that nobody reported the problem with standard SNAPSHOT dep. yet.

Comment: No, actually, it does not concern only classifier based artifacts. I just replied to you in the JIRA. It's a general problem. See my comment in the JIRA.

Comment: Good catch, thanks, 
Out of curiosity, are you M. Todorov then?

Comment: yep I did, can't wait for it to be fixed. 
My whole team is just lost as their understanding of maven is really shallow. Right now, they think they have to do a 'mvn install' to get a SNAPSHOT dependency updated... most practical way around this problem...
beautiful city you live in ;)

Comment: @carlspring let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1448/discussion-between-nodje-and-carlspring)

Comment: here we are a year later, and still no sign of a fix. @carlspring, you seem to suggest on JIRA that it occurs only when you've done a local install of the dep you're expecting an update, but we actually have the problem even for libs that haven't been installed locally. It really feels like the SNAPSHOT update mechanism is broken...

Comment: I hear you... :-|
You better put this in the JIRA issue.

Comment: I wonder if there is any hack which will make maven download the latest snapshot? Something like setting one of the timestamps in maven-metadata.xml to the far future.

Answer (score 1):

Is it this bug: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-4987 ? -> use maven 3.0.3